# JQuery - Serialize() a object that isn't a form but it's inside and part of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to serialize some contents inside of a form:

```
<form>
  <input ...>
  <input ...>
  <div id=div1>
    <input name=input1 ...>
    <input name=input2 ...>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  jQuery("#div1").serialize();
</script>
```

In this code serialize() function doesn't serialize the input1 and input2. Even I tried

```
jQuery("<form>" + jQuery("div1").html() + "</form>").serialize()
```

And it does serialize the inputs but all the values are Empty! it's like it doesn't assign values that user entered: `input1=&input2=`

Is there any solutions out there?
*(The reason I need to do this is that this page is a ASP.NET page since ASP.NET standard is a single form based so I have to deal with this situation)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this will work:

`jQuery('#div1 input').serialize()`

Comment: I was looking for a better solution, since it doesn't include textarea and other not input tags but still part of the form

Comment: `"I was looking for a better solution,"` I posted a better solution and your example of the , will also select textareas that are not in the div. It would have to look like `jQuery('#div1 input,#div1 textarea')`

Answer (score 12):

Better solution is to use the [:input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) since it gets all of the form elements

```
jQuery('#div1 :input').serialize();
```

Comment: it needs a space betweeb the `#div1` and `:input`. Otherwise it looks for a `#div1` that is (*itself*) of type `:input`